# Rails5(puma3.11)におけるHTTP parse errorの解消について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sslの設定を行い、「rails s」を行ったのち、`https://ドメイン名/` にアクセスしたところ、「HTTP parse error, malformed request」が発生しました。
解決方法がわからず、質問させていただきます。

また、ログやコンフィグ等解析に必要と考えているものを抜粋していますが、不足があればご指摘をお願いします。

---

◆ サーバログ

```
$ rails s -p 443 -b 0.0.0.0 -e production

Install the mechanize gem version ~>2.7.5 for using mechanize functions.
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.0 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:443
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-01-25 02:39:08 +0000: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

---

◆ config/environments/production.rb(抜粋)

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

---

◆ config/puma.rb（抜粋)

```
if "production" == ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }
  ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '443', {
    key: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/[ドメイン名]/privkey.pem',
    cert: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/[ドメイン名]/fullchain.pem',
    verify_mode: "none"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://qiita.com/zaru/items/ccf328e87c768168134d

上記ページによると、`rails s` でなく `pumactl` を使うようです。

```
RAILS_ENV=production pumactl start
```

でいかがでしょうか?

Comment: 無事アクセスできました！ありがとうございます！
備忘のため、使用したコマンドは以下の通りです。

sudo [プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/shims/pumactl start RAILS_ENV=production